# Left join two datatables- No SQL and no LINQ

Tags: vb.net, join, datatable

I have a dataset in my VB.NET solution. Let's say the dataset has 2 data tables (MyTable1 and MyTable2). Lets assume MyTable1 and MyTable2 are like:

MyTable1:

| Order | Account_Number | Account_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 10000000000001 | BlahA |
| 20000 | 10000000000002 | BlahB |
| 30000 | 10000000000003 | BlahC |

MyTable2:

| Order_Number | Line_Number | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 00000000034 | MD35Z |
| 15000 | 00000000530 | MX25A |
| 25000 | 00000024535 | P231Y |
| 20000 | 00000027735 | A511L |
| 30000 | 00000000910 | M232C |

Now I want to left join MyTable2 to MyTable1 and get the following result as my MyTable1:

| Order | Account_Number | Account_Name | Line_Number | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 10000000000001 | BlahA | 00000000034 | MD35Z |
| 20000 | 10000000000002 | BlahB | 00000027735 | A511L |
| 30000 | 10000000000003 | BlahC | 00000000910 | M232C |

To achieve this, I used LINQ, however, I was wondering if there is any way to use SQL queries when the datatables are not in a SQL database? (There is no db connection).

Comment: Not SQL queries exactly, but you can use a datarelation and expression columns within your dataset to achieve the same result.

Comment: There are a few methods and properties in ADO.NET that support a very limited subset of SQL code, e.g. `DataTable.Select` and `DataView.RowFilter`, but there's nothing like an actual join. LINQ has been specifically designed to do in managed code what SQL does in databases so why are you trying to not use the tool created for the job?

Comment: I see in a comment on a deleted answer that you don't like the fact that you have to create the schema of the output `DataTable`. Do you even need a `DataTable`? The LINQ query can generate a list of anonymous objects. Can you not just use that as is?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yes, I thought about using lists, however,  my preference would be using datatables, since those datatables are being updated and utilized all over the place.

Comment: One alternative would be to use a typed `DataSet` and then you can build a `DataTable` with the desired schema in the designer and then simply create instances of it as required. You'd still have to map data from your LINQ query to the `DataTable` but at least you wouldn't have to build the schema in code each time.